# Symfony Doctrine2: How do I work with limited one-to-many relation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity `Employee`

```
class Employee
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WorkHour", mappedBy="employee", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $workHours;
}
```

and `WorkHour`

```
class WorkHour
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Profile
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Employee", inversedBy="workHours")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $profile;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="weekday", type="smallint")
     */
    private $weekday;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hour_from", type="time")
     */
    private $hourFrom;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hour_to", type="time")
     */
    private $hourTo;
}
```

Now I'm confused when I'm going to add `addWorkHour()`, `removeWorkHour()` methods.

Usually one-to-many relation you can add as many relations as you want, but in my case, one employee can have only up-to-7 workHours, and for a specified `weekday` (from 0 to 6) can have only one (or no) record.

So I think what I need is something methods like,

```
public function setWorkHourByWeekday($hour_from, $hour_to, $weekday);
public function getWorkHourByWeekday($weekday);
```

And after set workhours for an employee, when you persist that employee, 
I want doctrine delete those workhours that are no longer exist, update those workhours that are changed, and create new workhours that not exist before.

How can I implement this? Should I write these logic in class `Employee` or its `Repository`, or a `WorkHourManager` class?

Answer (score 1):

I think `WorkDay` is a probably better name for your entity, so i'll use that :).

```
$workdays= $employee->getWorkDays();
$workdays->clear(); // Clear existing workdays

// Add new workdays
foreach(...) {
    $workday = new WorkDay();
    $workday ->setWeekday(0); // You could use a constant like `WorkDay::MONDAY`
    $workday ->setStart('09:00');
    $workday ->setEnd('17:00');
    $workdays->add($workday);
}
```

Set `orphanRemoval=true` on `$workHours` to remove `WorkHours` without an `Employee`.

The `setWeekday` method in your `Workday` entity should throw an exception when an invalid weekday is supplied (other than 0-6). You could also use a `Weekday` value object in combination with Doctrine embeddables.

I'd go for a service or manager class in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is not to drop old workhours, maybe you don't needed now, but this data could be useful in the future. So, will be better just add workHours to the Employee and make a report the get the last workHours for today. About validations, there is a lot of ways of doing that. If you are working with forms and the rules are complex maybe you need read http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html , but maybe you can find alternatives in the action controller or the entity class itself.